# How to create a topbar widget in GTK?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk, gtk3

I am building an app using GTK in C, and besides the graphical interface I want to have a topbar widget similar to the discord widget below.

Could you provide some information on how to build that?

[image: Like this]

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your widget using the Gnome Shell Extensions GJS Api and then talk to your main (c) application using dbus.